# TYPO3 Powermail static form template

Tags: php, forms, typo3, typo3-extensions

Usually in Powermail extension I create a form in the TYPO3 backend.
Is it possible to create a static form?

I want to achieve a form that is placed in the footer, so that the user cannot edit it.

Comment: Did you check with TypoScript to include it in the footer ?

Comment: Yes I did, but I have to create this form in the backend to include the form with typoscript.

Comment: You can create it in a folder that only administrator have access so the users can't edit it.

Comment: Thats true, but when I am installing a new template or page, then I have to create this form in my code and in my typo3 backend. Is there no way to create one only with code?

Comment: No it's not possible.